# in magento how can i Get related product in the product listing page

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am doing a magento project where i have to bring related product and upsell product in the product listing page which is product/list.phtml
i can get all the product details from

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
$_product->

but i can't get any related product and upsell product using  $_product->

please help me please

Answer (score 13):

You can do the following (inside the foreach loop)

```
$related_product_collection = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection();
$related_product_collection->AddStoreFilter();
```

Regards,
Kenny

PS: If you want to know which methods are available, you can always run the

```
var_dump(get_class_methods($_product)); die;
//or
Mage::log(print_r(get_class_methods($_product),true));
```

First one will print all available methods on the screen while second one will output it in the system.log located in the /var/log/system.log (make sure that in configuration->developer you have logging enabled of course)

Comment: Cool __get_class_methods($_product)__!

Answer (score 6):

You can pass product id for which you require related product.

E.g
You need related product for a particular product (Say $_product)

You can get related product ids by

```
  $_product->getRelatedProductIds()
```

You can see array of ids by :

```
  print_r($_product->getRelatedProductIds());
```

I hope this will help you.

Regards,
Kamesh J

Comment: awesome, just what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

On list page you get all product details with id.
using this code `$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(product_id);`
you get product for that id.

After use this code to get details of related product

```
$relatedProductsId=$_product->getRelatedProductIds();
    $relatedProducts=array();
     $i=0;      
    foreach($relatedProductsId as $relatedProductId)
    {   

        $relatedProducts[$i] =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($relatedProductId)->getName();

                $i++;
    }
```

and you get all related product